# Prove that $\left\vert\frac{a+b}{1+ab}\right\vert < 1$ given that $|a|<1$ and $|b|<1$

Tags: inequality

Can I please get a hint/solution for why, if true,

$$\bigg{|}\frac{a+b}{1+ab}\bigg{|}<1$$

given that $|a|<1$ and $|b|<1$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

I've tried the usual things like deleting something from the top/bottom or triangle inequality but I have no idea how to do it. Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Thanks

Comment: Consider $(1+ab)^2-(a+b)^2$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How would you know if this is strictly greater than 0?

Comment: By **considering** it.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry but I'm still not sure how to do it. It still seems like the same difficulty (trying to show the denominator is greater than the numerator). Can I have another hint please? Thanks

Comment: $(1-a^2)(1-b^2)$ is a continuation of the oceanic hint...

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense

Comment: See also: [Show inequality of complex number: $|\frac{a+b}{1+a\bar{b}}|<1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/734343) and [Show that $\frac{a+b}{1 + ab} < 1$ for $a,b < 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1374604). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7C%5Cfrac%7Ba%2Bb%7D%7B1%2Bab%7D%7C%20%3C%201%24&p=1). For more tips on searching, see: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show $ab+1 > |a+b|$ since $ab+1>0$.

Also, we may assume $a+b\geq0$.
(If not, substitute $\alpha = -a$ and $\beta = -b$ and consider the statement for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.)

Now $ab+1=(a-1)(b-1)+(a+b)>a+b=|a+b|$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense